# Better way of calculating sum of even ints

Tags: java, int, sum

I'm trying to write a programme to prompt the user to input an `int` which is above or equal 2. From this input the programme must then calculate and print the sum of all the even integers between 2 and the entered `int`. It must also produce an error message if the inputted `int` is below 2. I've made a programme for it that works but am just wondering if you guys could find a better way of doing it? I'm sure there is but I can't quite seem to find a way that works!

Here's what I did:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenSum {


         public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an integer which is above 2.");
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    int divnum = number / 2;
    int divnum2 = divnum + 1;
    int sumofeven = divnum * divnum2;

    if(number >= 2)
    System.out.println("The sum of the even integers between the number is "+
            sumofeven);
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid number entered.");


    }

}
```

Comment: Might be better-suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not sure.

Comment: @tjm no.. No offence but I wouldn't be getting homework in June. It's for exam preparation I'm trying to write short snippets of code to practice, however there's no mark scheme so I'm trying to get an opinion from people who are better at java than I am. @Rob, it probably is.. sorry I'm new around here.

Comment: My suggestion would be to check for invalid input before you go through the trouble of calculating your sum.

Comment: why not just use a for loop and step by 2?

Comment: @Jimmy, that's cool. No worries if it was either, just it should be tagged as such if it was. If you're looking for practice problems you might enjoy http://projecteuler.net/ if you don't know it already.

Comment: @Jimmy - No problem about being new around here. I'm not very familiar with CR anyway, so the line between here and there is blurry to me. I was just tossing it out there, in case you want the question migrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** do not use this example in a *real* context, it's not effective. It just shows a more clean way of doing it.

```
    // Check the input.
    if (number >= 2)
        System.out.println(sum(number));
} 

// Will find the sum if the number is greater than 2.
int sum(int n) {
    return n == 2 ? n - 2 : n % 2 == 0 ? n + sum(n - 2) : sum(n - 1);
}
```

Hope this helps. Oh, by the way, the method `sum` adds the numbers recursively.

**Sorry**, but I had to edit the answer a bit. There might still be room for improvement.

Comment: Given the OPs answer works in constant time for any value of 'n' and this answer takes increasing amounts of time until it get a StackOverflowError for even fairly small `n`, its not an improvement IMHO.

Comment: That is true, it is less effective in terms of memory usage, but it presents the task in a simpler way like most examples of recursion. :) It is difficult to tell what the asker means by *better*, it could be anything.

Comment: There. I added a note to it. :)

Comment: @Peter *it's not very effective*, the OP should remove **very**, it's plain ineffective to use recursion to calculation a simple function that requires O(1).

Comment: @Whirlwin, I disagree w/ the idea of elegance

Comment: @bestss I removed the "very". I don't know what what word to use besides "elegant" (and ineffective). Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: @Whirlwin, I know recursion looks 'clean' but I just dont consider it elegant when it's unnecessary (and esp. when it has obvious performance penalties). Learning recursion is truly important, though... just not when there is an O(1) solution. The OP had it right from the start, imo.

Answer (score 2):

Why do it with a loop? You can actually calculate it out. Let X be the number they choose. Let N be the largest even number <= X. (N^2+2*N)/4 will be your answer.

Edit: just saw the answer above me. He is right. I gave the function I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a loop at all? You are computing the sum of:

```
2 + 4 + ... n, where n is a positive even number.
```

This is a very simple arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an integer which is above 2.");

    int number = scan.nextInt();

    if (number >= 2) {
        int sumofeven = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i += 2) {
            sumofeven += i;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the even integers between the number is " + sumofeven);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid number entered.");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. That's the sort of thing I was trying to do.. I was actually going to try something like this but didn't think I could put a for loop in an if-else statement (not sure why lol.) Cheers!